# Google Sheets overtime calculation if/and/or statements

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a simple bi-weekly paycheck estimator in Google Sheets. Basically you put in the hours worked for Week 1 and Week 2, and I want it to automatically determine the amount of overtime for each week (hours over 40). I'm trying to do this with if/and statements but just can't seem to get the formatting/arguments correct.

Example of what I'm trying to do: A1 (Week1) = 39, and A2 (Week 2) is 45. It should determine no OT for week 1, but 5 hours for week two, and list a total of 5 OT hours in cell A3. Trying to do all of these calculations in one statement. I can get them working fine separately but can't get the formatting right to combine them. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have in `A1` (week 1, 39h) and in `A2` (week 2, 45h).

Your total overtime (5h) will be in cell `A3` with this formula:

```
=IF(A1>40;A1-40;0)+IF(A2>40;A2-40;0)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's exactly how I was trying to simplify the statement :)